# How do I do a GET Request on my Public Domain for AWS Lightsail Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, flask, server, flask-restful

I have a link below that was assigned to my current AWS lightsail Docker Container such as:

**https://*project-name*.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.cs.amazonlightsail.com/**

I allowed port 5000 to be enabled on my docker flask api and on my AWS lightsail container.
I want to do a GET Request on port 5000 to request the data from a certain subdomain.

The way I called the local host api was through
**127.0.0.1:5000/subject/number**

Therefore I was thinking I would call the API Public Domain like this:

**https://*project-name*.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.cs.amazonlightsail.com:5000/subject/number**

**Am I putting the port and subdomain in the correct place for the AWS domain?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are doing it correctly. It seems to me that if it is not working, it has nothing to do with the url, but rather with your security rules. Make sure you have publicly exposed port 5000.